# Execute scripts related to anchor onload

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of links anchored to hidden divs. These divs are hidden by setting the opacity to zero and I used jQuery to show these divs once I click on their respective anchor.

What I want to know is is it possible to open these divs using jQuery by just putting the anchors in the url? For example:

```
<a href="#div1">Link1</a>
<a href="#div2">Link2</a>
<a href="#div3">Link3</a>

<div id="div1">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div id="div2">Vestibulum in sollicitudin</div>
<div id="div3">Mauris auctor</div>
```

The divs are initially hidden and only appears when the anchor is clicked. Now how do I open a certain div, say div2, onload by just adding the anchor at the end of the URL, like `http://example.com#div2`

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Listening for window.onload event or even better the document.ready

Comment: @MiJyn I can't use display:none since I want to animate it. I'm also using toggleClass so I can also remove them after another click.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa so it's possible? I can show these divs by adding the anchor at the end of the URl?

Answer (score 1):

You use also use `toggle()`

```
$('a').click(function(event){
   var href = $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');
   $(href).toggle();
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Updates: I think there is a bug in above code.  Here is a working demo in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezepE/1/)

**jQuery:**

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(href).toggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: +1 - However, you should probably `return false` or use `event.preventDefault()` so the page doesn't jump on click.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for reminding otherwise one more question would have raised :).

Answer (score 0):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

function linkHandler(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var div = document.getElementById(event.target.getAttribute('href').replace('#',''));
    if(div.style.display == 'none'){
        div.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
    links[i].addEventListener('click', linkHandler);
}
```